# Firebase Storage IAM Permissions

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I tried to create a `storage`  product category in Firebase - the "Chat App" tutorial said "Production" mode so that's what I did. I immediately got the following error:

**Due to recent security improvements to Cloud Storage for Firebase, you must update your project settings.**

[image]

The spinner never really stops spinning. If I press the "Fix Issue" button, then I get the message "Due to a recent security improvement in Cloud Storage for Firebase, you need to grant an additional IAM role to a service account in this project."

[image]

If I click "Attach Permissions", I get yet another error message:

[image]

The console will not allow me to delete the storage, add new storage, or do anything else.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Firebaser here. This is a known issue with our Console that we're planning to fix in the near future.

In the meantime, you can follow this FAQ to repair your project: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts

In particular, you'll need to call the [AddFirebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/storage/rest/v1beta/projects.buckets/addFirebase) endpoint to re-link one of your storage buckets (e.g. your default `appspot.com` bucket). This should solve the permissions issue for you.

Comment: I ended up deleting and creating a new project, and it worked for me. Thank you for the FAQ, and the tip.