# how to fix storage unknown error has occured

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I'm getting an unknown error in firebase console, in other projects i can access it normally it seems to be exclusive to this project in my case.
[working storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Txz.png)
[storage with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjZYM.png)

tryed the solution it indicates but couldn't figure out whats wrong, by doing some research i found something about IAM permissions (?) but couldn't figure it out as well.
[after clicking fix issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbGDb.png)
[after clicking attach permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLvau.png)

tryed fixing it some more by myself, went to IAM and admin section and was comparing it with the other project that is working as I mentioned before.
[project with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDHah.png)
[working project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxXgw.png)
I added the role of storage admin for the default service account but i think thats not the right way of doing so.

I'm aware about [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76974100/firebase-storage-iam-permissions?rq=2) but i couldn't quite undersand it